# How can I force Google Music to re-upload all the tracks from an album?

Tags: google-play-music

I ripped two albums, but had to edit the tag information in all the tracks as it was either missing or wrong (all upper case in this case). As Google Music is looking at the same folder as I rip music to it started to upload the tracks before I had finished retagging and renaming them.

Google Music didn't upload all of the tracks for each album but thinks it did as if I select the folders explicitly it says "0 new songs". If I set the folder to the parent of the affected folders it says there are 141 songs in the folders - which tallies with the number of .mp3 files in those folders.

The closest information I've found is in [this Google support page about re-adding deleted music](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1267802?hl=en-GB) but the solution it suggests of editing the track information or pointing the uploader at a new folder and then back to the original one haven't worked. I even deleted the tracks that did get uploaded and it didn't work.

When I viewed my music online a day later I saw that somehow the other "half" of the tracks had indeed been uploaded with the incorrect filenames/tags. I deleted those as well, but still can't upload the now fixed files.

How can I just force Google Music to re-upload some files regardless of what state it thinks the files are in?

Comment: A bit of a pre-emptive workaround... rip the music to an entirely separate (temporary) folder, adjust tags, artwork, etc. then copy to your Google Music folder to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the following steps actually caused the songs to be reuploaded, or whether it was the specific order I tried them in tonight (which I didn't write down), but I tried:

1. Specifying the folders containing the tracks explicitly.
2. Pointing the manager at a completely unrelated folder and then back at my main music folder.
3. Retagging the tracks.
4. Closing and reopening the music manager between each step.

All of these were tried after I'd deleted the badly named/tagged tracks from the online library.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue; I logged out of the Windows Account, than logged back in and it than uploaded the new music added to existing folders.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the upload folder all together, quitting the app, re-adding the music library, and hitting upload seemed to do the trick.  Its annoying, as I have to do this every time I add music to my music library. It doesn't pickup the new tracks.

Answer (score -1):

I think retagging will do it but if that's a hassle, what I did was wipe it from the online library and place the songs in an unrelated folder and point at that to upload them and it worked.